# Derive subset with sum between two values

Tags: algorithms

I have a set `S` of size `n` whose members each have associated with them a number in the range `0.00` to `1.00` inclusive.

I want to select a subset `T` of size `m` with this property:

- the average of the numbers associated with the members of `T` must fall within a specified range `x` to `y` (for example, `0.65` to `0.75`). Expressed differently: the sum of the numbers associated with the members of `T` must fall within a specified range (for example, `0.65m` to `0.75m`)

Further, out of all the possible `T`s for a given `S`, `x`, `y`, I want to choose one (uniformly) randomly.

My current method is to randomly select `m` members of `S`, and then check if the sum falls in the desired range. I repeat until I get a satisfactory result.  Is there an algorithm (possibly dynamic programming?) to get the desired subset without using guess and check?

---

Example:

`S` is a set of `n = 200` questions, each assigned a difficulty rating between `0` and `1` inclusive. I want to generate a test `T` with `m = 50` questions where the average difficulty is between `0.65` and `0.75` inclusive. Furthermore I want to select a (uniformly) random `T`, out of all the possible `T`'s that satisfy my conditions.

Another Example:

```
S = {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0}
n = 5
m = 3
x = 0.5
y = 0.75

All possible T and their average value
{0.1, 0.3, 0.5} = 0.8 / 3 = 0.26
{0.1, 0.3, 0.8} = 1.2 / 3 = 0.40
{0.1, 0.3, 1.0} = 1.4 / 3 = 0.46
{0.1, 0.5, 0.8} = 1.4 / 3 = 0.46
{0.1, 0.5, 1.0} = 1.6 / 3 = 0.53
{0.1, 0.8, 1.0} = 1.9 / 3 = 0.63
{0.3, 0.5, 0.8} = 1.6 / 3 = 0.53
{0.3, 0.5, 1.0} = 1.8 / 3 = 0.60
{0.3, 0.8, 1.0} = 2.1 / 3 = 0.70
{0.5, 0.8, 1.0} = 2.3 / 3 = 0.76

Subsets of S with size m with average values between x and y
{0.1, 0.5, 1.0}
{0.1, 0.8, 1.0}
{0.3, 0.5, 0.8}
{0.3, 0.5, 1.0}
{0.3, 0.8, 1.0}
```

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to produce one of these 5 subsets at random, without first calculating every subset of S with size m.  It seems that guess and check is the best method.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem sounds similar

Comment: I'm wondering how you are defining the 'randomness' of the subset?

Comment: @DavidScholefield given that there are M subsets of size N that fulfill my condition, I want to select one of them at random.

Comment: Could you work through your problem? What are the constraints on the (sub)set? Are duplicates allowed? Are the values all integers? are they within a range? How do you handle that M may be a ***very*** big number? How random do you want the selection to be?

Comment: A subset of which set? An arbitrary set of integers of size >= N? Only positive integers? A subset of the set of all positive integers? Please clarify!

Comment: as you set requirements as to the result your polling is giving, you're no longer talking about anything random...

Comment: I've updated the question with more specific details and an example problem.

Comment: I've attempted an edit to restate the problem with all the comments incorporated/addressed, hopefully it hasn't changed the problem.

Comment: With the given example, 200 questions of which 50 are to be chosen, finding all the subsets of 50 that meet the requirement and choosing one at random is an unachievable task. There are 200 choose 50, or about 454 quattuordecillion (454*10^45), possible subsets. Some will be acceptable, others not. Your computer doesn't have the capacity to find all the acceptable subsets. Even Google or the NSA doesn't have that much storage (it's not even close).

Comment: @DavidHammen I understand it's not possible to find them all but is there a way to find just one?  Maybe by using some variation of the knapsack problem?

Comment: Re *Is there an algorithm to get the desired subset without using guess and check?* Let M be the number of questions whose ranking is between 0.65 and 0.75. The answer to your question is yes if M>N. Just randomly choose N of those M questions. Otherwise, the answer is no.

Comment: Solutions to the knapsack problem inevitably use what you call "guess and check".

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible to deterministically build such a random set in "one go", whatever it exactly means. However here is what I think is the closest alternative:

Start with N random numbers. As long as your average is not satisfying, randomly remove a number and replace it with a smaller/larger one. To quickly find the numbers to remove and their substitutes you could either split both your input and output sets in two (numbers below the wanted average versus numbers above the wanted average), or you could sort the input set and use binary searches.

An alternative yet similar idea is to start with an empty set and add "small" or "big" numbers depending on your current average. However you could find yourself with an invalid set in the end and you would then have to resort to method #1, so I think it is more elegant to only use #1.

Finally, regarding redundant values, I suggest to use a pre-processing step: sort your input set, then scan it to find redundant items and randomly pick one.

**Rephrased to clarify things up.**

Comment: I think both of these methods will create a bias for certain values.  i.e. if you the final subset does not meet the criteria, you remove a "bad" value (an outlier) and replace it with a "good" value.  This will result in "good" values being used more often and "bad" values being used less often.

Comment: @PrestonS - So what? This comment of yours suggests you have some addition requirements that you have not yet told us.

Comment: @DavidHammen No, I specified random which means an even distribution across all possible values.  Swapping out values in this way is definitely not random.

Comment: What does that even mean, Preston? You have not fully specified the problem.

Comment: @DavidHammen It means I'm looking for an algorithm to produce one subset that fulfills my criteria.  Then, if I ran the algorithm many times, it would eventually have returned all the possible subsets an equal amount of times.

Comment: @PrestonS The loss of randomness is introduced by your constrains on the average: we're removing big numbers when your average is too large and replace them with smaller items. This is as random as possible. Now I admit that the implementation where each set is split in two slightly skews the distribution, however the implementation with binary searches does not.